# Change NSAttribtuedString Formatting Starting at Index

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITextView` with attributes enabled, and I want to change the formatting (font/alignment/color/etc) within the `NSAttributedString` starting at a point. In other words, there is no specific part of the underlying `NSAttributedString` I want to change per se, I just want to make the next thing added into the `UITextView` have different formatting from what is in there so far.

For example, you might imagine a `UITextVIew` with a string inside it, and then the user enters a new line and taps a button to increase the font size. The user does not want to increase the font size of **everything**, just starting at that point.

Can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need precise control over the dynamic style behavior of your `UITextView` (and if you are >= iOS 7), you should consider using Text Kit, and in particular subclassing [`NSTextStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSTextStorage_Class_TextKit/index.html). There is a [introduction video to Text Kit from WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/), and a [great tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77092/text-kit-tutorial-swift).